# by Using Kivy how to switch between .kv files to open one window and close another

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

py files and 2 .kv file one of them is the mainApp.py and his kivy file is mainApp.kv
and the other is secondScreen.py and his kivy file is secondScreen.kv
now I want to switch between them to open one window and close the other
can any one help with that?

I am trying to open one .kv file and close the other

Comment: See [ScreenManager](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html).

Answer (score 1):

> You can use **Popen** to open another py(python) file.

```
class FirstScreen(Screen):
    btn = ObjectProperty(None)
    
    def btn_click(self):
        ffile = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\second.py"
        from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
        Popen(["cmd", "/C", "start " + ffile], shell=True)
```

Place the above function in the first py file from which you want to open another py file and give the file path properly.

> Don't forget to import:-
> **from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty**